# ATG - Endeca dimension value synonym

Tags: dimensions, atg, synonym, endeca

Is there a way to define dimension value synonyms for desired dimension values through ATG?

Comment: Version of products 11.2.

Comment: This can be done for product.category but not for other dimensions

Comment: Hi Ajay. Thanks for answering. Is there a workaround suggestion to define synonyms for other dimensions? The only way I could come up with is to manipulate CAS output in endeca side.

Comment: From ATG, you might need to customize so many things to achieve this. May i know what you try to achive?

Comment: I have some dimensions which are used for typeahead using the oob cartridge. Some values of the dimensions may have accents.  The goal is to get these values, as they are (accented), as typeahead suggestions when the input is unaccented.

Comment: try to create new exporter similar to CategoryExporter and put synonyms in xml file like category-dim-output-config.xml. I did for brand once same as Category

Comment: You have already been provided possible solutions for accented characters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995241/extend-endecas-diacritic-folding-mapping).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend Endeca's diacritic folding mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995241/extend-endecas-diacritic-folding-mapping)

Comment: Hi bated. Sure it is related but it is not just this case (accents) that synonyms could be used.

Comment: Regarding the syonyms I prefered a solution in Endeca side. Created custom component that modifies the dimensions.xml output file in cas_output folder before Dgidx takes over.